# AJAX API code check? Underground weather api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, debugging

Hello so I found a tutorial on how to create a simple weather app using the underground weather API. I literally copied the entire code (with very minor modifications) to see how the app would function, but it is not working. The relevant html is here:

```
<div class="container">

 <div id="forecast">
   <h1>Weather at <span id="location">
     </span></h1>
   <div id="imgdiv">
     <img id="img" src=""/>
   </div>
   <p>It is currently <span id="temp">
     </span> degrees F with <span id="desc">
     </span></p>
   <p>Wind: <span id="wind">
     </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Geo = {};
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }
  else {
    alert("Geolocation off");
  }

  function error() {
    alert("We couldn't find you");
  }

  function success(position) {
    Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert("Success");


   var key = "MYKEY"
   var Weather = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYKEY" +
   "/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/" +
   Geo.lat + "," + Geo.lng + ".json";

  $.ajax({
    url: Weather,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
    var location = data["location"]["city"];
    var temp = data["current_observation"]["temp_f"];
    var img = data["current_observation"]["icon_url"];
    var desc = data["current_observation"]["weather"];
    var wind = ["current_observation"]["wind_string"];


      $("#location").html(location);
      $("#temp").html(temp);
      $("#desc").html(desc);
      $("#wind").html(wind);
      $("#img").attr("src", img);

    },
    fail: function() {
      alert("Nah son");
    }
   })
  }

})
```

The HTML displays and on loading I'm greeted with an alert that says "Success", indicating that retrieving the geolocation wasn't the problem. But the text isn't changing to show the weather at all :/ So that is the part of my code that I need a review on.

I'm thinking that I must have have a problem with properly closing everything or with how I used $.ajax() as this has been causing me a lot of problems in other projects that I've been working on lately.

Any help would he very appreciated! I'm new to coding and so I apologize if I made a stupid mistake somewhere in there. Though by simply copying from another source and adding an alert and changing alert texts I don't think there will be a major flaw in there.

Here's a link to the article that I used to build this code: http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/09/how-to-build-a-weather-app-with-html5s-geolocation-api/

And here's underground weather's API documentation: https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api

Thanks for any help!

Comment: open console of browser  `Shift+Ctrl+C` (or `Shift+⌘+C`)and tell us what is the error there.

Comment: The console doesn't display anything, that's also confusing me

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
var key = "MYKEY"
   var Weather = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYKEY" +
   "/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/" +
   Geo.lat + "," + Geo.lng + ".json";
```

You missed the ";" after key declaration and assignment. And your Weather url is wrong bcz you are not passing the api key. It should be:

```
var Weather = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/”+ key +”/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/" + Geo.lat + "," + Geo.lng + ".json";
```

And key should be replaced with actual api key that you got from signing up in https://www.wunderground.com

Comment: That semicolon is probably the problem, wow can't believe I let that slip by. And yeah I pass in my key in the actual code, I just subbed in "MYKEY" here for privacy's sake. But thanks mate!